# Passing multiple arguments to event handle method

Tags: yii2

How do I let the event know that I'm needing to pass in 3 parameters to the handle method of my event.

**config/web.php**

```
'on eventname' => [EventName::class, 'handle'],
```

**app/events/EventName.php**

```
namespace app\events;

class EventName
{
    public function handle($arg1, $arg2, $arg3)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Signature of your event handler is incorrect. Event handler takes only one argument - event object. If you need to pass three arguments to handler, you need to create custom event object and use its arguments to store these values.

Create custom event:

```
class MyEvent extends \yii\base\Event {

    public $arg1;
    public $arg2;
    public $arg3;
}
```

Use it on event trigger:

```
$this->trigger('eventname', new MyEvent([
    'arg1' => $arg1,
    'arg2' => $arg2,
    'arg3' => $arg3,
]));
```

And use event properties in handler:

```
public function handle(MyEvent $event) {
    if ($event->arg1) {
        // ...
    }
}
```